# Convert a list of lists to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list containing six lists

```py
lst = [
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']
]
```

and I am trying to convert this into

```py
{
    "2.2.5": ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.5',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5'],
    "2.2.6": ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.6',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.6',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.6']
}
```

So far this is what I did:

```py
to_dict = {key[0]: [value[1] + '/' + value[0] for value in lst] for key in lst}
```

This returns

```py
{'2.2.5': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.6'],
 '2.2.6': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.6']}
```

The inner loop adds everything from the index `1` from `lst`. How should I add values appropriate to its key?

Comment: ah! yes should have used tuple when searching for this in Google

Comment: `dct = dict((a[0], [b[1]+'/'+a[0] for b in lst if b[0] == a[0]]) for a in lst)`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Could you add this as an answer? It's a good implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the list elements as key-value (python does the unpacking), and use **`dict.setdefault`** to set the value list as empty and append to the list:

```
In [77]: out = {}                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [78]: for k, v in lst: 
    ...:     out.setdefault(k, []).append(v) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [79]: out                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[79]: 
{'2.2.5': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All',
  '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',
  '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'],
 '2.2.6': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All',
  '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',
  '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']}
```

or **`collections.defaultdict`** with a `list` factory:

```
In [80]: out = collections.defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                                                                

In [81]: for k, v in lst: 
    ...:     out[k].append(v) 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [82]: out                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[82]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'2.2.5': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'],
             '2.2.6': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',
              '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']})
```

---

For appending the key string to value, use f-strings or `str.format` (on a version that does not support f-strings):

For `dict.setdefault`:

```
out.setdefault(k, []).append(f'{v}/{k}')
out.setdefault(k, []).append('{v}/{k}'.format(v=v, k=k))
```

For `collections.defaultdict`:

```
out[k].append(f'{v}/{k}')
out[k].append('{v}/{k}'.format(v=v, k=k))
```

Comment: is there any performance between these both approaches?

Comment: @Akshay Both are implemented in C, but the later imports a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
lst = [
['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'],
['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']
]
from collections import defaultdict
c=defaultdict(list)
[c[i].append(j) for i,j in lst]
print c
```

Output:
`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'2.2.5': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'], '2.2.6': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']})`

Answer (score 1):

Use `defaultdict` or `dict.setdefault()` method:

```
lst = [
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All'],
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'],
    ['2.2.5', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App'],
    ['2.2.6', '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App']
]

out = {}
for k, v in lst:
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v + '/' + k)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=30)
```

Prints:

```
{'2.2.5': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5'],
 '2.2.6': ['/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.6',
           '/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.6']}
```